# Repainting my lanai floor

Tags: concrete, painting

I'm painting my lanai floor and it has been painted last year but changing the color. Did one area and let it dry 24hr. and I can scratch it off/ I used the paint Home Depot sold me for concrete. What is going on???

Comment: Did you paint over the existing paint from last year? How did you prepare the floor?

Comment: Yes I painted over last years. Home depot told me all I have to do is paint over it and nothing else.

Comment: Big problem. Proper surface preparation is **crucial** for paint to adhere properly. Read the preparation and application instructions on the can... that's what you **should** have done. Shame on the "big box" and their personnel if they told you to paint without first preparing the surface, I hope they suffer continuous itchiness without benefit of scratching! Another reason for shopping at the local mom-and-pop paint or hardware store.

Answer (score 1):

If, after completely cured, the paint still exhibits the same poor adhesion characteristics, you will unfortunately have to scrape or strip all areas that are unsound (probably the entire coating). You must then properly prepare the surface (sand, sand, sand) then repaint.